# Top 10 values in range and return the value in the left most column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to look up the top 10 values in the range D2:L17 and return the corresponding value for the row that the top value is in in the range A2:A17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the first cell and copy down 10 rows.

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$2:$L$17)/($D$2:$L$17 = LARGE($D$2:$L$17,row(1:1))),1))
```